# How do i know if my touch screen has HW problem after flashing

Tags: touchscreen

My device [ SGH-i957 ] Worked perfectly on HC 3.2, After flashing the ICS official update, my touch screen stopped working.

How do i know if it is HE or SW problem ?

NOTE: i can use ASM normally to get my current tablet screen displayed on my ubuntu laptop if that matters

Comment: I have also tried androidscreencast.zip , no luck their as well

Comment: ASM? What's that...?